# Resharper 5+ only works intermittently ... any suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

We had a bunch of computers at work running VS2010 with Resharper.  In VS2008, Resharper ran slow enough that all the other devs stopped using it ... even those on quad core boxes and 8GB+ of memory.  In VS2010, Resharper 5+ starts up great and works fine ... but then within ~4 hours starts to go downhill.  We first notice that simple functions like "Find Usages" return bogus results (or nothing), then it slows down considerably, and finally the mouse stops working (while the keyboard becomes extremely slow).  Our project isn't huge either - we only have 5 developers who have been working for a year, so I imagine there are far larger projects using Resharper.

Any suggestions?  4 of the 5 devs on my team have stopped using Resharper altogether, the other is getting ready to.  We all have different configurations, computers, and even OS's, but all have similar problems.

Thanks!

Comment: I run R# 5.1 on VS2008 all day and seldom have an issue (speed or otherwise), and my workstation is several years old. Some solutions contain 10-20 projects. That's in C#, though; VB may be different.

Comment: Sounds like ours.  17 projects, 1MM lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your results don't sound typical. We have a million-line codebase, and although we did have speed problems with 5.1's test runner (as a result of which we've downgraded back to 5.0), we haven't had any problems like what you're describing.

What sort of project are you writing? R# 5.1 had several fixes for ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC, and I think there were performance fixes in there too (I didn't pay too much attention since we don't do Web development). If you don't mind a slow test runner and you're doing Web development, try upgrading.

Otherwise, I would suggest that you either write up the issues you're seeing in [ReSharper's bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/dashboard), or contact ReSharper support via their "[Problem Using ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=ReSharper&ask=Problem)" contact form. They might be able to be of assistance, and in the case of the slowdowns they might be able to walk you through getting a profile so they can see what's wrong.

Comment: We are using 5.1.  It's far better than 5.0.  Our solution is 17 projects, about 1 Million lines of code (which doesn't seem terribly big, at least compared to other codebases we've created), and the problems now only occur after a few hours (where before they were happening right away).  

I originally contacted ReSharper, they finally said they'd need our solution to see the problem, which we can't provide for confidentiality reasons.  I'll probably try again, I just wanted to see if anyone here had problems.

Answer (score 1):

According to JetBrains, it's likely a memory issue caused by using Visual Studio (32 bit) on a 64 bit OS (non-Win7).   See:  http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5262347#5262347

> The second issue is a probable bug in the Windows code. If you're running
>   a 32-bit application on more than 2 GB of virtual memory, then getting the
>   mouse cursor position fails when you allocate memory above the first two
>   gigs. Visual Studio is a 32-bit process and, when run on a 64-bit OS, can
>   access something about 3.5 GB of memory. WPF uses GetCursorPos to see where
>   you clicked. Sometimes it allocates memory below 2GB, sometimes above. In
>   the latter case, you lose. Mouse clicks, that is. We were experiencing these
>   problems on VS 2008 as well, but there's just so little WPF code, and other
>   things would not usually rely on getting the mouse position explicitly.

Until you can upgrade to win 7, the workarounds I've found include

- Hit the ALT key.  This seems to allow you to click, but you pretty much have to keep hitting it any time you switch windows
- Restart visual studio
- Disable resharper

Comment: Have you contacted JetBrains support?

Comment: I haven't as it sounds a lot like this known issue (http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5262347#5262347) and I've noticed it happens even when resharper is disabled, though much less frequently.