# VS2010 editing XAML files is unresponsive to mouse clicks

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm wondering whether other users of VS2010 are experiencing the same problems as me.

I find I have to restart VS several times a day after the XAML editor becomes unresponsive to mouse clicks. I've tried submitting a Connect issue but got nowhere with that.

My environment is:

Quad core machine runing Vista 64 with 8GB RAM.
VS2010 SP1 - had the same problems with VS2010.
ReSharper 5.1.3

Editing Silverlight XAML files - I have the split screen with preview at the top and the XAML at the bottom. After some time of working, if I click in the XAML the carret doesn't move to the clicked position. Other parts of VS are unresponsive to mouse clicks as well. Basically I have to shut down VS and restart.

Of course, this is difficult to reproduce - it generally only happens after several hours of running.

Anybody got any ideas on how to fix this, or better bring it to Microsoft's attention?

**Update:**

Here's the link the the Microsoft Connect item I entered.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/618594/xaml-designer-stops-responding-to-mouse

Comment: Can you post a link to the Connect bug that you filed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar issues where the mouse stops responding on certain windows when resharper is running.  The only solutions I've found so far are:

- Hit the ALT key (discovered the mouse becomes active after this, but you have to keep hitting it every time you switch windows)
- Restart visual studio
- Disable resharper

**Update:**

This is essentially a Vista 64 problem but ReSharper exacerbates the problem through large memory use. Upgrading to Windows 7 64 bit solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the ALT key tip - that gets me out of the issue temporarily.

Comment: Are you really sure it's ReSharper though?

Comment: I've discovered the root explanation, it's likely a memory issue caused by using Visual Studio (32 bit) on a 64 bit OS (non-Win7). See this question for more details:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384413/resharper-5-only-works-intermittently-any-suggestions/6124934#6124934

Comment: Denis - you're definitely right on this. I've now upgraded my machine to Windows 7 64 bit and VS is now very stable. The problem has certainly gone away.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common problem, you should check out some other references, but a few thigns you can do are;

1. Replace the XAML editor with something else (Blend maybe)

   - Right click on a XAML file, goto "Open With" then select an alternative editor and also select the set as default option.
2. Open the XAML editor in Full screen source mode by default.  This will bypass a lot of the design time compilation's
3. Close other windows, in visual studio when your editing the XAML, perticularly the properties display.  I've found that this window frequently queries the design time model of your code to display properties and such (if you dont want them triggering all the time, close the window and that thread will be idle).

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm hoping that Microsoft will fix what is clearly a bug.

Comment: Closing properties gave me a big boost regarding the strange "lockdown" when intellisense enumerates some list in XAML (f.ex. WPF's 'WindowStartupLocation' or 'HorizontalAlignment').